# Query dinámico vba sql access

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

Solicito de su ayuda con lo siguiente:

Tengo un proyecto con interfaz vba (excel) y base de datos access, lo que quiero es poder tomar los valores de una tabla de access y ponerlos dentro de un query como parte del select

Ejemplo:

```
Tabla_campos
Id - Nombre
1    Identificacion
2    Obligacion
3    Fecha
4    ......
N    ........
```

```
  SELECT Identificacion,Obligacion,Fecha FROM Tabla_campos;
```

Como dice el título de query dinámico hago referencia a que debo armar el select partiendo de los datos registrados en la tabla del ejemplo.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. Con un SELECT te traes los registros. ¿Qué problema tienes?

Comment: Y cual seria el problema? que intentaste?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Elier Sanchez, lo que no puedo hacer (no se como) es poner los registros de la columna de la tabla como campos del select.

Comment: *lo que no puedo hacer (no se como) es poner los registros de la columna de la tabla como campos del select.* No entiendo. ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo? Pon tu input y el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Sabiendo donde están los datos que necesitas meter en la consulta es sencillo pasarlos a una variable y meter ésta en el SELECT de la query:

```
nombre_provincia = sheet1.cells(1,1).value

Select * FROM PROVINCIAS WHERE PROVINCIAS.nombre = '" & nombre_provincia & "'
```